# Storing dynamic content | Variable amount of elements

Tags: mysql

I need to store this relation:

```
domain -> tag1, tag2, tag3 .... tagN
```

to a msql table.

I figured I would just have two fields like this

```
domain | tag_arary
```

Actual data might be:

```
facebook.com | [social, networking, web, foo1, foo2 ]
```

Or another way, would be to set a maximum amount of tags and just have a field for each tag:

Structure

```
domain | tag1 | tag2 | tag3
```

Actual Data

```
facebook.com | social | networking | web | foo1 | foo2
```

What is the best way to implement this.

Make note, I'll need to add tags, and remove tags.

Thanks

Comment: why not 2 tables? domain and tags (id, domain_id, tag) - easier to search, remove, edit. No problem with tag length and escape special characters

Comment: ...I don't have a problem with tag length or special characters.  What do you mean?

Comment: Every column in mysql has some limit - it depends on column type, check manual for details. Special character, assume you choose | (pipe) as a tag separator, what happen if I decide create new tag "Drinks|Rum" <- this is one string

Comment: I meant that to be pseudo code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the most flexible way for the long run, as it's **much easier** to **query/update/delete** the tags. You might want to **give id** to the domains table though, as it would be much faster in terms of searching on integer field.

```
CREATE TABLE domains (
 domain VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY
);

# table to store all your domain names
INSERT INTO domains (domain) VALUES ('www.facebook.com');

# table to store all the tags you want to have for your application
CREATE TABLE tags (
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
tag_name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO tags (tag_name) VALUES ('social');
INSERT INTO tags (tag_name) VALUES ('networking');

# Then, you can store all the tags related to a domain in domain_tags table
# It provides one-to-many relationship between a domain and tags.
CREATE TABLE domain_tags (
    domain VARCHAR(255),
    tag_id INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO domain_tags (domain, tag_id) VALUES ('www.facebook.com', 1);
INSERT INTO domain_tags (domain, tag_id) VALUES ('www.facebook.com',2);

# Whenever you want to get the tags for a domain, simply join the tables together
# and query based on your domain name.
SELECT tag_name
FROM domains d
INNER JOIN domain_tags dt ON d.domain= dt.domain
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id= dt.tag_id
WHERE d.domain='www.facebook.com';
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Comment: See my edited comments in the code may be. For more info about why this design is preferable, check [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/)

Comment: This is normalized but the indexes on the join_table will be quite wide, which is not very good.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by index will be quite wide? If domain name length is a concern, we can always create an ID for each domain name. So the join table will just have 2 integer columns.

Comment: Yes, that would be far better than two `VARCHAR` columns, 8 bytes vs 514 is a big difference.

Comment: You also have a typo: `tag_id VARCHAR(255)`. It should be `tag_id INT`

Comment: true, was meant to make tag_id an integer. Thanks for pointing out!